# I need Each Link To Open In New Tab In This PHP Code

Tags: php, html

I have a php script to generate links as anchor text but what I want is that each link should open in a new window. I know we have to use

```
target="_blank"
```

but the problem is that where should I type this target="_blank" in this php script, if I type it next to urls then it gives me some kind of error.

```
<?php

echo '<h3>Drop some urls in the box, then click the button<br />
<FORM name="urlbox" action="" method="POST">
<textarea style="background:#eee;" rows="20" cols="30" name="rawurls"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Make Links" name="submit">

</FORM>
';

$rawurls=$_POST["rawurls"];

$explodedurls=explode("\n",$_POST["rawurls"]);
echo '<pre>';
$i=1;
foreach ($explodedurls as $eachurl) {
        echo "<a href=$eachurl>Youtube Video $i</a><br>";
                    $i++;
            }
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: `some kind of error` -- What kind? What's the exact error message?

Comment: It says ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_blank' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\Convert.php on line 18

Comment: You aren't escaping the double-quotes. Use the following instead: `echo "<a href=\"$eachurl\" target=\"_blank\">Youtube Video $i</a><br>";`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `<a>` tag itself .. Like this..

```
echo "<a href=$eachurl target='_blank'>Youtube Video $i</a><br>";
```

Comment: Are you sure about your single/double quotes?

Comment: This still gives an error Shankar. John answer is the correct one. Anyway, Thanks

Comment: @MackieeE, That is valid. Variables will be parsed inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$eachurl` contains a valid URL:

```
echo "<a href=\"$eachurl\" target=\"_blank\">Youtube Video $i</a><br>";
```

The error is probably due to the fact that you don't have quotes around your `href` URLs. It is also possible they contain quotes and break your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
echo '<a href="'.$eachurl.'" target="_blank">Youtube Video '.$i.'</a><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error because you are using double quotes`"` inside double quotes`"` also you are not having quotes around `$eachurl`

```
foreach ($explodedurls as $eachurl) {
    echo "<a href='$eachurl' target='_blank'>Youtube Video $i</a><br>";
                $i++;
        }
```